# How can I install more recent versions of software than what Debian provides?

Tags: debian, apt, backports

Suppose I want a more recent version of software than is available for my current version of an operating system, what can I do?

Cases to consider:

1. There are semiofficial/official sources of additional packages
   available for that version of the OS. E.g. backports.org for Debian
   or PPAs for Ubuntu.
2. There are no more recent versions of the package available for that
   version of the OS, but there are more recent versions available for
   more recent versions of the OS. This is the standard case for
   backporting.
3. There are no packaged versions of more recent versions of the
   software available. Options available are to package the more recent
   version.

---

<sup>Per [Let's compile a list of canonical Q&As](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2708/4671) this is intended as a place to put canonical answers for the following. Answers should probably be made community wiki.</sup>

Comment: This is highly distribution-specific. Better make it one question per distribution.

Comment: @Gilles The question is not distribution-specific. I think it would be better to have one question, with answers for different distributions.

Comment: **One example of what did and did not work:** For Debian 8 I wanted MySQL 5.6. *(But normally MySQL 5.5 is only installable for Debian 8. I needed 5.6 for comparability with other things I was doing.)* I tried to install the 5.6 backport but it was broken. *Some sort of duplicate file being loaded error message.* I reported it but then what to do? **The solution:** I discovered that you could download MySQL 5.6 specifically for Debian 8 directly from the MySQL site. That worked, BUT... be sure to read the WORKAROUND comment at the bottom of [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-i

Comment: You can always compile the package yourself from scratch and install it to a directory in your $HOME.  That was what we did in the old days.  If we had a compiler!  Ooh we used to DREAM of a compiler....  We had to bang rocks together to get zeros and ones!  If we were LUCKY!

Answer (score 52):

**(If you have questions/comments about this answer, please add a comment. Or, if you have sufficient rep, you can ping me in chat.)**

## Directly installing binary packages from a newer version of Debian - not the answer.

Suppose you are running some version of a Debian-based distribution. You want a more recent version of a package than is available to you. The first thing that every beginner tries to do it to install the binary package directly on your version of Debian. This may or not work, depending on what version you are running, and how much newer the package is. In general, this procedure will not work well.

Consider for example the case where one is trying to install a binary package from testing/unstable directly on stable. This will most likely not go well, unless testing/unstable happen to very close to stable at that moment. The reason has to do with the nature of a Linux-based binary distribution like Debian. Such operating systems depend heavily on shared libraries, and these dependencies are often very tightly version-dependent; often much more so than necessary. Debian currently does not have a good way of making version dependencies "tight" - a shorthand way of saying that the version dependency is exactly as restrictive as necessary.

What does this mean for the user? Suppose for example that you are trying to install say `slrn` from Debian unstable to Debian stable. What would this look like?

```
# apt-get install slrn/unstable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '1.0.1-10' (Debian:testing [amd64]) for 'slrn'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 slrn : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.13-38+deb7u1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Despite the error produced by `apt`, there are no broken packages here. So, what went wrong? The problem is that the version of `libc6` that the unstable `slrn` was compiled against is different (and has a higher version number) than the one available on Debian stable. (`libc6` is the GNU C library. The C library is central to any Unix-like operating system, and GNU C library is the version that Linux-based operating systems generally use.)

Therefore the unstable `slrn` requires a higher numbered version of `libc6` than is available for stable. Note that because a package has been compiled against a higher version of library does not necessarily require a higher version of that library, but it is often the case.

The syntax

```
apt-get install slrn/unstable
```

means: use the unstable `slrn` but for all other packages only use the versions from stable. To be more precise, it uses priority numbers. See `man apt_preferences` for details.

One can also do

```
apt-get install -t unstable slrn
```

This is much more likely to work, but you generally don't want to do it. Why?

This means: temporarily treat *all* packages in unstable on an equal footing with the packages in stable. Therefore this will pull in the unstable `slrn`'s dependencies from unstable if they are of a higher version number, and they generally will be. This will generally include the GNU C library for reasons already explained. Now, this approach will generally "succeed", in that the dependencies will be satisfied by definition (unstable's `slrn` has dependencies which are satisfied in unstable), but you end up with a mixture of packages that suddenly are being forced to run with versions of libraries different from what they were built for. This will probably not end well.

### The answer is... BACKPORTS!

So, what is the correct way to do this? It is to rebuild the Debian sources of more recent versions on your system, popularly known as "backporting".
Consider the following cases:

> There are semiofficial/official sources of additional packages available for that version of Debian.

The first place to look is [Debian Backports](http://backports.debian.org), which is the official site for Debian backports.

For a concrete example:

Add the appropriate backports line for your release and update to find the new packages then install something from backports explicitly (because backports are deactivated by default).

```
echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -t stretch-backports git
```

This will get the latest stable version of git which has useful newer features than the stable one included with stretch (e.g. 'include' which allows you to combine multiple config files or change your username for ~/work/projects/ vs ~/personal/projects/).

Another place to look at is the various PPAs by Ubuntu maintainers. You can do a search for "packagename PPA".

> There are no more recent versions of the package available for that version of the OS, but there are more recent versions available for more recent versions/releases of the OS. This is the standard case for backporting.

Backporting means that you rebuild the Debian sources from a later version of Debian on the version you are running. This procedure may be easy or involved and difficult depending on the package. Here is an outline of how to do this.

## A Brief Backporting Tutorial for Beginners

For concreteness I will assume you are running the current Debian stable, currently wheezy. I'll use the package `slrn` as an example.

First, note that all the Debian packaging files live in the `debian/` subdirectory of the source directory.

The first step is to check whether a more recent version is available. You can do this using `apt-cache policy`.

```
apt-cache policy slrn

slrn:
  Installed: 1.0.0~pre18-1.3
  Candidate: 1.0.0~pre18-1.3
  Version table:
     1.0.1-10 0
         50 http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
         50 http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.0.0~pre18-1.3 0
        500 http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.0~pre18-1.1 0
        500 http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
```

We would like to backport `1.0.1-10`.

STEP 1:

**NB: Make sure that the `deb-src` lines for the source version you want to download appears in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.** For example, if you want to download the unstable version of `slrn`, you need the `deb-src` line for unstable, or it won't work. Note that you don't need the corresponding `deb` lines to download the sources, though `apt-cache policy` uses that information, so if you don't have the corresponding `deb` lines, then `apt-cache policy` won't show you the relevant version(s). If you do have the `deb` lines, don't forget to pin the newer versions using an entry in `/etc/apt/preferences` or similar. An entry in `/etc/apt/preferences` like this (for unstable) will work, for example.

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 50
```

If you add lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, don't forget to run `apt-get update` afterwards.

Download the sources for `slrn`. A good place is `/usr/local/src/slrn`.

```
apt-get source slrn=1.0.1-10
```

STEP 2:

Change the version number slightly, so as to distinguish your backport from the upstream version. Run `dch --bpo`, which will automatically add an entry to the `debian/changelog` file with an appropriate version number, for example

```
slrn (1.0.1-10~bpo10+1) UNRELEASED; urgency=low

  * Backport to buster.

 -- User <user@domain>  Sun, 02 Feb 2014 23:54:13 +0530
```

STEP 3:

Attempt to build the sources. If the packages required for the build are not available, then the attempt will fail. Change directory into the source directory. Use `debuild` from the `devtools` package.

```
cd slrn-1.0.1/
debuild -uc -us
```

If the build dependencies are satisfied, then the sources will build and produce some debs at the level above the source directory; in this case `/usr/local/src/slrn`.

STEP 4:

Suppose the build dependencies are not satisfied. Then you need to try to install the build dependencies. This may or may not work, as the dependencies may not be available for your version, or if available, may not be available in the right version.

**NB: It is unfortunately not uncommon for Debian packages to require versions of build dependencies that are higher than necessary.** There is no automated way in Debian to check this, and often package maintainers don't care as long as it works on the corresponding version/release. Therefore, take a skeptical attitude to dependency versions, and use common sense. For example, widely used packages like Python and the GNU tools will not depend on very specific versions of their dependencies, regardless what the Debian packager lists.

In any case, you can try to install them doing

```
apt-get build-dep slrn=1.0.1-10
```

If this succeeds, then try building the package again (STEP 2). If it fails, then further work is needed. Note that `debuild` looks at the Build Dependencies in the `debian/control` file, and you can change these if necessary. So let us talk about that now. Here are the Build Dependencies for slrn.

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>=9), libslang2-dev, libuu-dev,
 exim4 | mail-transport-agent, libgnutls-openssl-dev, po-debconf, autoconf,
 libcanlock2-dev, autotools-dev, dpkg-dev (>= 1.16.0), chrpath, dh-autoreconf, inn2-inews
```

An alternative to using `apt-get build-dep` is to install these manually, by doing

```
apt-get install debhelper libslang2-dev ...
```

If you start changing these values in the control file, then you should switch to a manual installation, as then `apt-get build-dep` will no longer be doing the right thing.

> There are no packaged versions of more recent versions of the software available. Options available are to package the more recent version.

In many cases, one can reuse the packaging from earlier versions of the software in conjunction with newer sources. This approach can run into problems, notably patches that applied to earlier versions of the software may not apply here, so one may need to resync them with the sources. The 3.0 (quilt) source format which is now becoming standard uses quilt, and patches are located in the `debian/patches` directory.

However, a detailed discussion of these issues is out of scope for this post.

Comment: This is really distribution generic (only that the code repositores for newer stuff can be called differently, or you'll have to get stuff from special places). Check your distribution's guides.

Comment: This (backporting) will be really useful in some situations, but seems likely to be fairly difficult in others. [@dirkt answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395253/286615) using `stow` seems more *generally* useful & *easiest*. But @StephenKitt comment re [pragmatic packaging](https://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2016-pragmatic-debian-packaging) seems a good compromise... `just right` according to Goldilocks :)

Comment: @Seamus Backporting much of the time is not hard. Sometimes it can be challenging. Typically more complex packages with a larger number of dependencies are harder to backport, as one would expect. Simpler packages with a fewer number of dependencies are easier. Personally, I find I can do a successful backport most of the time.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Perhaps - I don't have much experience. The `mtr` package seemed it might be a reasonable candidate. My `buster` system has *v 0.92*, whereas [the upstream `mtr`](https://github.com/traviscross/mtr) is at *0.95*, but when I looked at the dependencies in the debian source package I changed my mind. Is it easier than I thought?

Comment: @Seamus I just built mtr 0.95 on buster. It only took a couple of minutes. It has hardly any dependencies.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: What worried me were the dependencies on `libgtk2.0-dev` & `libjansson-dev` shown in: `apt-cache showsrc mtr-tiny`  - I didn't see the point of `libgtk2.0-dev` in `mtr-tiny` & `libjansson-dev` was a dependency only in 0.94 (bullseye). Anyway - will you answer a "how-to-do-this" question if I ask?

Comment: @Seamus Sure, but there is very little to do. Just try the obvious and it works. And I don't recommend worrying about *why* the dependencies are what they are. That way lies insanity. If you do ask a question, mention what you tried first, and what problems/errors you had.

Answer (score 6):

One way that always works, not only in Debian, is compiling the necessary software yourself. (I've been doing this for years now on Debian, both when I needed a newer version that was available, and when the software was not provided at all).

I store locally compiled packages in `/use/local` using `stow`, which allows me to store all files related to a package in a subdirectory tree, and then to make symlinks to that tree. That makes managing compiled packages easy: Installed files don't collide with Debian-provided files, and I can remove a package with one command.

The steps to compile and install a package, say `some_software`, are usually a variant of the following:

1. Download `.tar` file etc. into `/usr/local/src/`.
2. Create a file `/usr/local/packages/some_software` that describes where I downloaded the software, what it does, what version it is, and that contains notes what I had to do to make it compile (see below).
3. Unpack contents of `.tar` file into `/usr/local/tmp/some_software`.
4. Alternatively, if compiling from a repository, check out the repository in a suitable subdirectory (e.g. `/usr/local/git/some_software`), and compile there,
5. `cd` into this directory, look at `README`, `INSTALL` etc.
6. In most cases, there's an autotools script to `configure` the package. Call with `./configure --prefix /usr/local/stow/some_software-version` so files get installed in this subdirectory. Otherwise, read `Makefile` and figure out how to set the path for installed files.
7. Compile with `make`.
8. Install with `make install`.
9. `cd /usr/local/stow`, then `stow some_software-version`
10. Test if it works.

Often compiling doesn't work in the first attempt: The package may need libraries and the corresponding include files, so one has to install the correct `...-dev` packages from Debian. Or `gcc` may complain about stuff that a different version of `gcc` which the author of the package used doesn't complain about. So sometimes one has to read code, and fix these, but that doesn't happen too often.

Comment: The intention of this question, though perhaps this was not clear, was to describe how to install packages of software for Debian. Maybe I should make the question clearer. Does `stow` create Debian packages? From the man page, it doesn't look like it.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Stow does not know about Debian packages. It only manages symbolic links from a set of separate installation directories to a single directory.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: If you want to turn self-compiled software into a *Debian package*, then you have to package it up yourself, just like a Debian package maintainer. But that's too much trouble if you are going to be the only user, installing it in `/usr/local` is vastly simpler, and `stow` helps to manage the files stored there. Or put differently: Software doesn't have to be in a Debian package in order to use it on Debian.

Comment: There is one big advantage to packaging software as a Debian package, even for local use only: if you describe the dependencies correctly, having a package installed will ensure the dependencies remain installed...

Comment: @StephenKitt: If course packaging software properly as Debian package is the superior solution. The downside is that have to invest the time to package it properly ...

Comment: @dirkt I wasn’t disagreeing with you, I just wanted to point out the main advantage of packaging v. using Stow (IMO). There’s a place for both approaches depending on the amount of time one is willing to spend ;-). (Also, “... to package it properly” for some value of “properly”; [pragmatic Debian packaging](https://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2016-pragmatic-debian-packaging) gives a simplified approach which works well in many cases for local packages, while still documenting build and runtime dependencies.)

Comment: What is the point of appending `-version` in the final step (9): `stow some_software-version` ?

Comment: @Seamus (1) I want to keep track of which version is installed just by looking at the directory (2) sometimes I have several versions installed at the same time (e.g. libraries). (3) It makes upgrading easier (keep old version, compile new version, then unstow + stow, delete directory with old version).

Comment: This is a great answer, and it was helpful to me. The only possible *exception* I take is wrt the following statement: "`One way that always works, not only in Debian, is compiling the necessary software yourself.`". Consider this example: User running a release version more than 2 generations ago (*e.g.  jessie*), and has no developer tools installed (*i.e. no `devscripts` package available*). Unless you know some way to *"bootstrap"* these tools, it seems to me that building from source will work only as long as the user has (or can get) the required tools.