# cannot find php5-sqlrelay package

Tags: debian, apt, php

why i cannot find php5-sqlrelay package is there any issue with my update

```
        aptitude update


        Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg
        Hit http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy Release.gpg
        Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release
        Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
        Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Sources
        Get: 1 http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy-updates Release.gpg [836 B]
        Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy Release.gpg
        Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
        Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages
        Get: 2 http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy-backports Release.gpg [836 B]
        Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
        Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release
        Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy Release
        Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
        Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages
        Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
        Hit http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy Release
        Get: 3 http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy-updates Release [124 kB]
        Get: 4 http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy-backports Release [147 kB]
        Hit http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy/main Sources
        Hit http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        Hit http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy/main i386 Packages
        Hit http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy/main Translation-en
        Get: 5 http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy-updates/main Sources [4,478 B]
        Hit http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
        Hit http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
        Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Sources
          404  Not Found
        Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main amd64 Packages
          404  Not Found
        Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main i386 Packages
          404  Not Found
        Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-en_US
        Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-en
        Hit http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex
        Get: 6 http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy-backports/main Sources/DiffIndex [7,819 B]
        Get: 7 http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy-backports/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [7,819 B]
        Hit http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy-backports/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
        Hit http://cloudfront.debian.net wheezy-backports/main Translation-en/DiffIndex
        Fetched 292 kB in 9s (29.4 kB/s)
        W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources: 404  Not Found
        W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages: 404  Not Found
        W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-i386/Packages: 404  Not Found
        E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
        E: Couldn't rebuild package cache

        W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
        W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
        W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
        W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
        W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
        W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
        W: You may want to update the package lists to correct these missing files
```

and then i searched

```
        root@ aptitude search php5


        i   libapache2-mod-php5                                              - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
        p   libapache2-mod-php5:i386                                         - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
        p   libapache2-mod-php5filter                                        - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (apache 2 filter module)
        p   libapache2-mod-php5filter:i386                                   - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (apache 2 filter module)
        p   libexpect-php5                                                   - expect module for PHP 5
        p   libexpect-php5:i386                                              - expect module for PHP 5
        p   libgv-php5                                                       - PHP5 bindings for graphviz
        p   libgv-php5:i386                                                  - PHP5 bindings for graphviz
        p   libow-php5                                                       - Dallas 1-wire support: PHP5 bindings
        p   libow-php5:i386                                                  - Dallas 1-wire support: PHP5 bindings
        p   libphp5-embed                                                    - HTML-embedded scripting language (Embedded SAPI library)
        p   libphp5-embed:i386                                               - HTML-embedded scripting language (Embedded SAPI library)
        i   php5                                                             - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
        p   php5-adodb                                                       - Extension optimising the ADOdb database abstraction library
        p   php5-adodb:i386                                                  - Extension optimising the ADOdb database abstraction library
        i   php5-cgi                                                         - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
        p   php5-cgi:i386                                                    - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
        i   php5-cli                                                         - command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
        p   php5-cli:i386                                                    - command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
        i   php5-common                                                      - Common files for packages built from the php5 source
        p   php5-common:i386                                                 - Common files for packages built from the php5 source
        i   php5-curl                                                        - CURL module for php5
        p   php5-curl:i386                                                   - CURL module for php5
        p   php5-dbg                                                         - Debug symbols for PHP5
        p   php5-dbg:i386                                                    - Debug symbols for PHP5
        i   php5-dev                                                         - Files for PHP5 module development
        p   php5-dev:i386                                                    - Files for PHP5 module development
        p   php5-enchant                                                     - Enchant module for php5
        p   php5-enchant:i386                                                - Enchant module for php5
        p   php5-exactimage                                                  - fast image manipulation library (PHP bindings)
        p   php5-exactimage:i386                                             - fast image manipulation library (PHP bindings)
        p   php5-ffmpeg                                                      - audio and video support via ffmpeg for php5
        p   php5-ffmpeg:i386                                                 - audio and video support via ffmpeg for php5
        p   php5-fpm                                                         - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
        p   php5-fpm:i386                                                    - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
        p   php5-gd                                                          - GD module for php5
        p   php5-gd:i386                                                     - GD module for php5
        p   php5-gdcm                                                        - Grassroots DICOM PHP5 bindings
        p   php5-gdcm:i386                                                   - Grassroots DICOM PHP5 bindings
        p   php5-geoip                                                       - GeoIP module for php5
        p   php5-geoip:i386                                                  - GeoIP module for php5
        p   php5-gmp                                                         - GMP module for php5
        p   php5-gmp:i386                                                    - GMP module for php5
        v   php5-idn                                                         -
        v   php5-idn:i386                                                    -
        i   php5-imagick                                                     - ImageMagick module for php5
        p   php5-imagick:i386                                                - ImageMagick module for php5
        p   php5-imap                                                        - IMAP module for php5
        p   php5-imap:i386                                                   - IMAP module for php5
        p   php5-interbase                                                   - interbase/firebird module for php5
        p   php5-interbase:i386                                              - interbase/firebird module for php5
        p   php5-intl                                                        - internationalisation module for php5
        p   php5-intl:i386                                                   - internationalisation module for php5
        v   php5-json                                                        -
        v   php5-json:i386                                                   -
        p   php5-lasso                                                       - Library for Liberty Alliance and SAML protocols - PHP 5 bindings
        p   php5-lasso:i386                                                  - Library for Liberty Alliance and SAML protocols - PHP 5 bindings
        p   php5-ldap                                                        - LDAP module for php5
        p   php5-ldap:i386                                                   - LDAP module for php5
        p   php5-librdf                                                      - PHP5 language bindings for the Redland RDF library
        p   php5-librdf:i386                                                 - PHP5 language bindings for the Redland RDF library
        p   php5-mapscript                                                   - php5-cgi module for MapServer
        p   php5-mapscript:i386                                              - php5-cgi module for MapServer
        p   php5-mcrypt                                                      - MCrypt module for php5
        p   php5-mcrypt:i386                                                 - MCrypt module for php5
        p   php5-memcache                                                    - memcache extension module for PHP5
        p   php5-memcache:i386                                               - memcache extension module for PHP5
        p   php5-memcached                                                   - memcached extension module for PHP5, uses libmemcached
        p   php5-memcached:i386                                              - memcached extension module for PHP5, uses libmemcached
        v   php5-mhash                                                       -
        v   php5-mhash:i386                                                  -
        p   php5-ming                                                        - Ming module for php5
        p   php5-ming:i386                                                   - Ming module for php5
        p   php5-mongo                                                       - MongoDB database driver
        p   php5-mongo:i386                                                  - MongoDB database driver
        v   php5-mssql                                                       -
        v   php5-mssql:i386                                                  -
        i   php5-mysql                                                       - MySQL module for php5
        p   php5-mysql:i386                                                  - MySQL module for php5
        p   php5-mysqlnd                                                     - MySQL module for php5 (Native Driver)
        p   php5-mysqlnd:i386                                                - MySQL module for php5 (Native Driver)
        p   php5-odbc                                                        - ODBC module for php5
        p   php5-odbc:i386                                                   - ODBC module for php5
        p   php5-pgsql                                                       - PostgreSQL module for php5
        p   php5-pgsql:i386                                                  - PostgreSQL module for php5
        p   php5-ps                                                          - ps module for PHP 5
        p   php5-ps:i386                                                     - ps module for PHP 5
        p   php5-pspell                                                      - pspell module for php5
        p   php5-pspell:i386                                                 - pspell module for php5
        p   php5-radius                                                      - PECL radius module for PHP 5
        p   php5-radius:i386                                                 - PECL radius module for PHP 5
        p   php5-recode                                                      - recode module for php5
        p   php5-recode:i386                                                 - recode module for php5
        p   php5-remctl                                                      - PECL module for Kerberos-authenticated command execution
        p   php5-remctl:i386                                                 - PECL module for Kerberos-authenticated command execution
        p   php5-rrd                                                         - rrd module for PHP 5
        p   php5-rrd:i386                                                    - rrd module for PHP 5
        p   php5-sasl                                                        - Cyrus SASL extension for PHP 5
        p   php5-sasl:i386                                                   - Cyrus SASL extension for PHP 5
        p   php5-snmp                                                        - SNMP module for php5
        p   php5-snmp:i386                                                   - SNMP module for php5
        p   php5-sqlite                                                      - SQLite module for php5
        p   php5-sqlite:i386                                                 - SQLite module for php5
        p   php5-svn                                                         - PHP Bindings for the Subversion Revision control system
        p   php5-svn:i386                                                    - PHP Bindings for the Subversion Revision control system
        p   php5-sybase                                                      - Sybase / MS SQL Server module for php5
        p   php5-sybase:i386                                                 - Sybase / MS SQL Server module for php5
        p   php5-tidy                                                        - tidy module for php5
        p   php5-tidy:i386                                                   - tidy module for php5
        p   php5-tokyo-tyrant                                                - PHP interface to Tokyo Cabinet's network interface, Tokyo Tyrant
        p   php5-tokyo-tyrant:i386                                           - PHP interface to Tokyo Cabinet's network interface, Tokyo Tyrant
        p   php5-vtkgdcm                                                     - Grassroots DICOM VTK PHP bindings
        p   php5-vtkgdcm:i386                                                - Grassroots DICOM VTK PHP bindings
        p   php5-xcache                                                      - Fast, stable PHP opcode cacher
        p   php5-xcache:i386                                                 - Fast, stable PHP opcode cacher
        p   php5-xdebug                                                      - Xdebug Module for PHP 5
        p   php5-xdebug:i386                                                 - Xdebug Module for PHP 5
        p   php5-xmlrpc                                                      - XML-RPC module for php5
        p   php5-xmlrpc:i386                                                 - XML-RPC module for php5
        p   php5-xsl                                                         - XSL module for php5
        p   php5-xsl:i386                                                    - XSL module for php5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php5-sqlrelay is only available in unstable for m68k in the debports repos:
https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=php5-sqlrelay

If you have a suitable processor (m68k), then read this for details on how to install a package from testing:

[How to pull dependencies for package/testing from testing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114723/how-to-pull-dependencies-for-package-testing-from-testing)

Comment: how can i install it in debain

Comment: i tried this `gdebi php5-sqlrelay_0.39.4-6_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
Building data structures... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: phpapi-20060613

`
but it gives me an error

Comment: Edited answer. Please open a new question if you have other issues.