# Razor-Qt in Debian Wheezy?

Tags: repository, debian, razor-qt

I have Debian 7.3 Wheezy, KDE desktop and I want to install a light-weight desktop environment, based on Qt (like KDE, so I don't need to install too many dependencies).

I need to install razor-qt via CLI.

This is my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file - do I have to modify it?

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-        free

#Nvidia drivers repos
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

#deb http://deb-multimedia.org wheezy main
```

Comment: There is a razorqt in testing/unstable. From the build dependencies, it doesn't look like it would be hard to backport. Whether it would run correctly on wheezy is harder to say; things like desktops need to be integrated into the system. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671. If you need more help/information, please ask.

Comment: I'm not an expert Debian user, I can follow step-by-step installation guides and know some very basic CLI commands but going on to install backports is not my thing. Maybe I should wait for a stable version of razorQt though [their website states](http://razor-qt.org/): "Debian users can install it from the official repositories."

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty trivial to backport. If you really want I can stick the binaries somewhere (assuming your arch is amd64) but you are really better off going through the steps yourself.

STEP 1: build and install `libstatgrab-dev`. This is a build dependency for `razorqt`. The required version of `libstatgrab-dev` is not available in stable, so backport that yourself. Fortunately that is easy.

```
mkdir libstatgrab
cd libstatgrab
apt-get source libstatgrab
cd libstatgrab-0.90/
debuild -uc -us
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i libstatgrab9_0.90-1_amd64.deb libstatgrab-dev_0.90-1_amd64.deb
```

STEP 2: build `razorqt`

```
mkdir razorqt
cd razorqt
apt-get source razorqt
cd razorqt-0.5.2/
sudo apt-get build-dep razorqt
debuild -uc -us
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i [whatever you want, it is a bunch of stuff]
```

I haven't tried installing these binaries, but

```
sudo dpkg -i --simulate *.deb
```

doesn't complain about the `razorqt` deb files. I'm unsure whether this action actually checks for dependencies; I haven't used it before.