# How to update application on Debian?

Tags: debian, upgrade, wine

When I run

```
 a@debianVM:~$ wine --version
```

I get:

```
wine-1.4.1
```

And the website says:
 Latest stable release: Wine 1.6.2

How to update?

Answer (score 2):

Wine 1.4 is the latest official version in the debian repositories (see https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/wine).

**But**, you can install the sources from the wine website:

First you need to install required packages:

```
apt-get install flex bison qt3-dev-tools qt4-qmake
```

Then download the sources with wget:

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/wine/wine-1.6.tar.bz2
```

Unpack them:

```
tar -xjvf wine-1.6.*
```

And compile:

```
cd wine-1.6.*
./configure
cd tools; ./wineinstall
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to [backport](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671) Wine from unstable. This looks like it should be do-able, though perhaps not totally trivial. If you want more information on how to do this, please ask.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to update your repository database first (this will not update any packages):

```
 apt-get update
```

Then update wine:

```
 apt-get install wine
```

To update all packages on the system:

```
 apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Not working, probably 1.4 is the newest in official reppositories.

Comment: Using: http://www.fandigital.com/2012/05/install-latest-wine-in-debian-linux.html

Comment: The last wine version in repositories is 1.4.1.

Comment: The question was quite generic thus my answer.