# How to compile a Debian package from source?

Tags: debian, package-management, source

I use a tool called YUMI to create a USB boot device.

Its Debian package and its source can be downloaded from http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/.

I needed to change a file in source code to make the program fits my needs but now I don't how to compile it and install it afterwards.

I tried with `dpkg` but with no experience and it didn't work.

So, is there an easy way to compile and install a user-modified source code?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671 for related discussion. "I tried with dpkg but with no experience and it didn't work." does not help anyone trying to help you. Please paste commands used and errors encountered. Thanks.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thanks for the advice. I'd have helped myself if I had done that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy way to compile a package from source is with `dpkg-buildpackage`. Make sure you have `build-essential` installed. And `fakeroot` as well. Then:

1. All of this is done inside the package directory. If you're in the right directory, there should be a `debian/` subdirectory, containing `debian/control` and `debian/rules` (and probably more stuff, too).
2. Run `dpkg-checkbuilddeps`. Install any missing dependencies.
3. Edit `debian/changelog` to add a new changelog entry, with a new version. Otherwise apt will be annoyed. Alternatively, install `devscripts` and use `dch -l`.
4. Run `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -uc` to build the binary package only, `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc` to build binary and source packages.
5. You should now have some new `.deb` files in the parent directory, ready to be installed with `dpkg -i`

Comment: I guess now I know it didn't work. Source codes didn't include `debian/control` and `debian/rules`. Gonna try this with another source. Bookmarked. Thanks.