# Make Ubuntu acknowledge that a custom built version of PHP is installed

Tags: ubuntu, php, configure, multithreading

I'm trying to install PHP from source code on my Ubuntu 12.04 VPS.

I'm installing PHP like this:

1. Download the latest version from the php.net website.
2. Configure it using the parameters below.
3. Install any dependencies when necessary. (libxxxxx-dev)
4. Then do a make
5. Then a make install
6. Move the php.ini file and the fpm configuration files in the right place

I'm using these parameters in the configure command:

```
--enable-intl
--with-openssl
--without-pear
--with-gd
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr
--with-png-dir=/usr
--with-freetype-dir=/usr
--with-freetype
--enable-exif
--enable-zip
--with-zlib
--with-zlib-dir=/usr
--with-mcrypt=/usr
--with-pdo-sqlite
--enable-soap
--enable-xmlreader
--with-xsl
--enable-ftp
--with-curl=/usr
--with-tidy
--with-xmlrpc
--enable-sysvsem
--enable-sysvshm
--enable-shmop
--with-mysql=mysqlnd
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
--enable-pcntl
--with-readline
--enable-mbstring
--with-curl
--with-pgsql
--with-pdo-pgsql
--with-gettext
--enable-sockets
--with-bz2
--enable-bcmath
--enable-calendar
--with-libdir=lib
--enable-maintainer-zts
--with-gmp
--enable-fpm
```

Now, this goes all well and good. The version works as expected and during the installation I had no trouble. Now the fun stuff comes. Whenever I want to install something like `mcrypt` (for example) I would normally type `apt-get install php5-mcrypt` but when I do, and take a look at the dependencies I see that PHP5 is still listed as one and will be installed once I hit `y` (overwriting my own version).

Now the real core of my question is, how do I let Ubuntu know that I already have PHP5 installed so that it does not attempt to install PHP5 as a dependency anymore. Do I have to change something in the configure process? Do I have to install PHP5 using the `apt-get` manner first, remove it manually, and install my own version of PHP after.

It is worth mentioning that I need this custom PHP build to make Pthreads work since there isn't a repo that offers a ZTS version of PHP (yet, please make one, somebody?).

Comment: How exactly you compile your own version of PHP?

Comment: Ok, first, I'm reluctant to help anyone in the misguided endeavor of installing PHP, custom or otherwise. You really, really don't want to do that. Rethink it, please. You still want to? Are you sure? Ok, then the correct thing to do it to download the Ubuntu PHP package sources, configure *those* and then rebuild them. That way you will have an Ubuntu package you can then install, which your system will know about. You probably need more details. Feel free to ask. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157. This is about backporting, but it covers the basics of customizing packages.

Comment: I'm really unfamiliar with back porting. Tbh this is the first time I hear about it. I'll read some posts about it and when I have questions, I'll respond on this question. Thanks for the effort anyway.

Comment: @MartijnRiemers This isn't backporting, it is customization. Not really the same thing, but the basic machinery is similar. BTW, if you want someone to be notified of your comment, you need to prefix your comment with the username with an @ in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several alternatives here:

1. Add the `--prefix=/usr/local` to the configure script (assuming this is what PHP uses) or otherwise ensure that your PHP is installed to `/usr/local`. This would mean that you would have your own build of PHP installed alongside the system one. Since, for example, `/usr/local/bin` takes precedence over `/usr/bin` in `PATH`, your own build will be used in many of the cases (particularly when starting from the command line). By default this shouldn't interfere with the system packages which may have been built against a particular version of PHP and be broken if they try to use libraries provided by your own build. With this approach though you do need to pay some attention to which programs are using which libraries, however it should be possible to do this without problems.
2. Find a packaged version of PHP that is closer to your needs. If it is a newer version, there are plenty of Ubuntu ppas that offer this (preferably look in official 'backport' repositories first since anyone can create a possibly broken ppa). Note that this may also cause conflicts which force you to install other packages from the ppa (or leave you screwed if they are unavailable).
3. Download the source package and recompile it. This might be what you need to do if you want custom build options. There are many tutorials throughout the internet for this, but basically you would add the necessary `deb-src` lines to your `sources.list` file (or `sources.list.d`) and download with `apt-get source` (or just download the necessary files directly from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)). Extract with archives `dpkg-source` Then you would tweak the build options within the package `debian` directory, build with `debuild` or `dpkg-buildpackage` and install with  `dpkg -i`. You can even do this with a package from a ppa if you also need a newer version (although same caveats apply).
4. Finally the most difficult option is to create your own package. Starting with one of the above source packages and using different version of the upstream source than is otherwise available is a good place to start. However, here is completely up to you to ensure that the package plays nicely with the rest of your system.

Comment: @Martijn Riemers Yes, no 3 is what I had in mind. I would not recommend 1. Having two versions of a package installed is always a recipe for trouble.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha, 3 seems the best option to me. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @Graeme If I do it like way 3, will Ubuntu know I installed PHP5 then?

Comment: @MartijnRiemers, of course, yes. What you create is a package, much the same as the one you usually install with `apt`.

Comment: @Graeme I finally managed to pull it off. Thanks so much! I owe you one haha

Answer (score 0):

Ok, instead of the method you mentioned at first try this:

First, make sure you have `deb-src` entries in your `sources.list` file and you have run `apt-get update`. It will make the steps below easier. Now install building tools:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts
```

install your build dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep php5
```

Get the sources of php5:

```
apt-get source php5
cd php5*
```

You will notice that apart of downloading the sources, it also applied patches. Now look for the configuration script, which is in `debian/rules`. There's an entry called `COMMON_CONFIG`, edit it as you like:

```
editor debian/rules
## add, remove, change the configuration and save the file.
## You will find that most of them are enabled by default,
## or already included.
```

I would recommend to bump the version of PHP using `dch -i`. Now you are ready to build your stuff:

```
debuild -us
```

This will create the files ready to install in the parent directory. Now, you really should reconsider why you need to build stuff from source. Most of the security issues are fixed immediately there's a fix available, and due the nature of PHP (being something used in production), it's recommendable to use the official packages instead.