# How to update Wine in Debian Wheezy?

Tags: linux, debian, wine

I'm trying to run Wine with the game EVE Online. It pops out an error

```
Error: Procedure not found. Could not load python dll
```

However. Then I figure I'll try updating the Wine to a newer version. I'm currently on Debian Wheezy stable. I saw on some forums:

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

But that doesn't work. I have the version 1.4.1. How do I update Wine? Do I have to get Debian unstable instead?

Comment: You can do a backport from Debian unstable to stable, probably. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671

Answer (score 0):

The application EVE looks to require Python. For this you'll need to install Python into WINE itself. Wine will not make use of the Python that's installed on Linux, it will need to be the Windows version which will be installed into WINE.