# Install package pacemaker-mgmt on debian wheezy

Tags: gui, debian, pacemaker

I want to install a GUI for Pacemaker on Debian Wheezy. I've seen that it is available only in the unstable branch.

However I've added unstable branch to apt get sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ unstable main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ unstable main non-free contrib
```

I'm not able to install the packet because of unresolved dependencies:

```
apt-get install pacemaker-mgmt 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pacemaker-mgmt : Depends: libcib1 (>= 1.1.7) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libcrmcluster1 (>= 1.1.7) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libcrmcommon2 (>= 1.1.7) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libpe-status3 (>= 1.1.7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I solve this? Is there another GUI for pacemaker available which also runs on Debian Wheezy?

Comment: What you want to do is build a backport. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671 . From a brief look at the package you mentioned, it looks like it would be straightforward, though still some work. If you want further details, ask.

Comment: finally I installed it from source