# Build Transmission 2.84 .deb package with checkinstall

Tags: debian, compiling, make, compiler, checkinstall

I'm trying to compile and make by myself some .deb packages to keep my Raspbian more up to date than the repository. Now I want to update Transmission to v 2.84.

Here's what I've done:

1. Download the tarball from Transmission web site: https://www.transmissionbt.com/download/
2. Install checkinstall from Raspbian repository: `$sudo apt-get install checkinstall`
3. Extract source from tarball
4. `./configure` from transmission source directory
5. `checkinstall --install=no` from transmission source directory

Now I've a armhf .deb, but if I install it with `dpkg -i transmission_2.84-1_armhf.deb` I have only a partial installation. The installation completes correctly but I don't have:

- Transmission configuration directory and files (should be `$HOME/.config/transmission-daemon`)
- Boot/startup script for daemon on `/etc/init.d`
- I don't really know if something else is missing...

I want to generate a **COMPLETE .DEB package** with all the necessary files like official repositories .deb packages. I'd also like to do the same with some other applications, like `htop`. What should I do?

**UPDATE**

These are the steps I made to try to compile version 2.84 with debian directory taken from version 2.82:

1. download tarball with `wget https://transmission.cachefly.net/transmission-2.84.tar.xz`
2. extract archive on my source directory with `extract transmission-2.84.tar.xz` (extract() is a function in aliases, so it's equivalent to `tar xvJf ...`)
3. download debian folder of version 2.82 with `wget http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/t/transmission/transmission_2.82-1.1.debian.tar.xz`
4. extract archive inside transmission 2.84 directory with `extract transmission_2.82-1.1.debian.tar.xz` that created a `debian` directory inside `transmission-2.84/` directory
5. `./configure` from `transmission-2.84/` directory
6. after successfully configure, `sudo checkinstall --install=no` from `transmission-2.84/` directory. `checkinstall` will execute `make` and `make install`. With option `--install=no` it execute only `make` and then create a `.deb` package inside the `transmission-2.84/` directory
7. `dpkg -i transmission_2.84-1_armhf.deb` to install package
8. configure transmission settings on `~/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json`
9. `sudo nano /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon` to create init.d boot script
10. `update-rc.d transmission-daemon defaults` to link the new script
11. `transmission-daemon` and `sudo service transmission-daemon start` to try to start transmission

Comment: The correct thing to do here is to rebuild the Transmission debian sources on your platform. For more details, see [this question/answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671). If you need more details, please ask.

Comment: Yes... but I've no problems with the compilation. I only need to make a complete .deb package with all the correct files inside so then all files will take place on various directories (config file, init.d script, ...). So, if the solution for me is to reuse the previous version (2.52) packaging, what should I pay attention to?
I'm rebuilding it directly on my Raspberry, without cross-compiling.

Comment: Not following. "what should I pay attention to"? meaning what?

Comment: If I want to reuse the previous version packaging, what have I to do? What, where and how files/directories do I need to take from v2.52 and put on v2.84? And what may I need to possibly change on some of those files/directories?

Comment: First, you need to get the debian sources for the version you want. You want 2.84, right? Did you look at my backporting question link above? I see unstable has 2.82. Can you live with that? If not, you can probably use the 2.82 packaging with the 2.84 upstream source, but this would be a bit more work, and you might have to adjust Debian patches if any.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote on the question I already have the sources of 2.84 from Transmission web site and correctly compiled them. I also have last stable sources of 2.52 from Raspbian stable repository.

Comment: Yes, I read what you said. My point was, if you want to use the Debian packaging, you can use it directly with 2.82, or you can adjust it to work with 2.84. Which option do you prefer? To be clear, the idea is to build a Debian binary package that you can then install on your system.

Comment: Oh sorry! Yes... I think I can use the 2.82... But I'd also like to make it work with 2.84... I can try both ways!

Comment: Fine, first try 2.82 and see if it works. Are you clear about what you need to do?

Comment: I want to create a complete .deb package for my own compilation of Transmission v2.84 so I can use it to install on another Raspberry or later on on the same, without recompiling.

Comment: You are doing a custom build of transmission? I suggest you first try to build the vanilla debian sources for 2.82. if that works, you can proceed.

Comment: I'm going to try... after lunch! :-D

Comment: I tried to use debian folder of v2.82 with v2.84. The compilation of 2.84 went fine and also the .deb package creation with `checkinstall`. When I install it with `dpkg -i` the installation completes and now there're also configuration files but no `init.d` script. I made it using the 2.52 version that should work. Anyway, even after setting configuration for daemon, it doesn't start. If I type `transmission-daemon` or `sudo service transmission-daemon start` I get nothing...

Comment: I'm confused by the mention of checkinstall. You shouldn't be using checkinstall - there is no need. Can you give your steps in more detail in the body of the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15801/discussion-between-rainbowcoder-and-faheem-mitha).

Comment: More details in steps 1, 2, 3 and 4, please. Give the exact commands you typed.

Comment: I noticed that the program starts, but only with `sudo transmission-daemon start`. If I try to execute it with `sudo service transmission-daemon start` it doesn't work. I figured out that even copying the debian folder from 2.82 version, not all the correct configuration was made during installation of my .deb package. In fact there was no `debian-transmission` user in `/etc/passwd` and no directories `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info` and `/etc/transmission-daemon/`. Don't know what to do now... The compilation works, but the deb package is not complete...

Comment: You may not be building the package correctly. I lost track of where we were. Does the 2.82 package work properly for you? I need to go eat, but we can talk later, if you want. In the main chat room, preferably. Depending on your time zone.

Comment: Here it's 16.00 now. So ok... but I don't know how to access the chat...
I'm now trying to make a new experiment... install official transmission v2.52 from repository and then, after configuration, update it with `dpkg -i` with my .deb... Let's see... :-)

Comment: The chat link is at the bottom of the page - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux

Answer (score 1):

The files you say are missing, is because only Debian provides them, transmission sources doesn't have any init script to start. So as you noticed `checkinstall` can't figure this out. The best course of action is copying the `debian/` directory of upstream and compiling using `debuild -us -uc` instead.