# Alsa driver update in client machine without make

Tags: debian, upgrade, alsa

I have a Debian 6 system and updated alsa from 1.0.23 to 1.0.25, It works as expected.

Steps which I performed to compile:

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

Now , I have 100's of client machines in which I need to deploy this ALSA update. But, these machine does not have make/setup tools install.

To deploy this update what is the best way?

I even tried creating a package using CHECKINSTALL.

So, with created package I deployed it in 5 machines, in 3 machines the driver got updated and 2 machines reports no information on soundcard.

Am i missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does squeeze not have a 1.25 backport? If not, you can create your own by backporting the squeeze Debian sources. It's not hard. See [How can I install more recent versions of software than what Debian provides?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671) Once you have alsa binary packages, you can create an apt repo and pull from that. Don't use checkinstall.

If you want more details, please comment.

As far as the machines not recognizing the soundcard, that should really be a separate question.

Comment: Seems Debian 6 backports has updated kernel version..But, I need to investigate for proper functionality of other connected peripherals before updating.It might take some days of efforts.With #alsa support grou, we made the jack detection with existing alsa driver (1.0.21) without updating the version.

Comment: Actually, squeeze has 1.0.23.

Answer (score 0):

Please learn to use your linux distribution of choice.  I suggest reading of an appropriate book or reading the many excellent web resources for its use.

[This explains how to use packages in debian](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html)

Comment: I ran check install to create DEB packages.And deployed in client..Interestingly the deb worked successfully in lab machines but in production machine when we tried..We see no sound card getting detected.

Answer (score 0):

The `alsa-driver` package is outdated; the sound drivers are part of kernel, and are updated by updating the kernel package.

See [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)