# How to install meld 3.11 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, python

I am trying to get meld 3.11 to work on ubuntu 14.04

I tried following the method below"

```
cd ~ 
git clone https://git.gnome.org/browse/meld 
cd meld  
sudo ln -s ~/meld/bin/meld /usr/bin/meld
```

But when i run meld in the terminal i get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/meld", line 223, in <module>
    setup_settings()
  File "/usr/bin/meld", line 197, in setup_settings
    cwd=melddir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
   OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am not sure if its dependencies issue or python path problem.

Comment: Check the README for directions on installing.  It's located in the meld folder...  It has a setup.py.  It also has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Try doing a backport. 3.11 is available packaged for debian experimental, at least. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671. If you want more information about this, please say so.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
#Make a clean working directory
mkdir -p work/crap
#Get in to that directory
cd work/crap
#Clone git head
git clone https://git.gnome.org/browse/meld
#Get in to that project directory
cd meld
#Install dependencies
sudo apt-get install intltool itstool gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 libxml2-utils
#Install meld
sudo python setup.py install
```

If you wanted to work on the code itself without re-installing, I typically do that by installing in a venv and opening the installed to folder in the venv in an IDE.

Result of running meld in a terminal after those steps:

### [image]

Note that the current version of meld requires GTK+ 3.14, which is not available on Ubuntu 14.04 (`Meld requires GTK+ 3.14 or higher.` error). So for Ubuntu 14.04, you need to checkout the last version that does not need GTK+ 3.14. That is the meld 3.14.* branch (currently 3.14.3), so checkout the branch using `git checkout meld-3-14`.

Comment: i am going to try your method now.

Comment: I got the following after doing the final step.

.....

unable to execute 'glib-compile-schemas': No such file or directory.
......

Comment: either i have a dangling dependency from my current install that i can't see, or you have broken packages or you're using a broken distro or custom themes that break stuff.  in any case
, it works here

Comment: if you asked what you think are ubuntu related questions on AU or searched there, you would find this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/161739/why-does-launchpad-fail-to-find-glib-compile-schemas-while-building-for-ppa which points to this libglib2.0-bin as the dangling dependency, but i digress...

Comment: I had to install the dependancy libglib2.0-dev and libgee-dev and python-cairo for it to work.

Comment: I had to install libxml2-utils

Comment: I am getting "Meld requires GTK+ 3.14 or higher" after following the above steps any suggestions on what to do ?

Comment: I'm getting this error: `unable to execute itstool: No such file or directory` when running `sudo python setup.py install`. Could you suggest a fix? I'm on CentOS, followed your direction except for using `yum` in place of `apt-get`.

Comment: The current version of meld requires GTK+ 3.14, which is not available on Ubuntu 14.04 (`Meld requires GTK+ 3.14 or higher.` error). So for Ubuntu 14.04 you need to checkout the last version that does not need GTK+ 3.14. That is the meld 3.14.* branch (currently 3.14.3), so checkout the branch using `git checkout meld-3-14`.

Answer (score 1):

I found meld 3.12 available in ubuntu 14.10 repository.

deb package installation works even under 14.04

http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/all/meld/download

Comment: My repository still shows only 1.8.4 and your link is broken :(

Comment: Yep 14.10 support ends a long ago

Comment: Here's the link for the [Meld package on Ubuntu 16 (Xenial)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnome/meld). The package is about 2 years behind the [current version](https://git.gnome.org/browse/meld/refs/tags).