# How can I effectively purge a manually installed package?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, binary, uninstall

I installed SBCL 1.2.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 by downloading [sbcl-1.2.3-x86-64-linux-binary.tar.bz2](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sbcl/sbcl-1.2.3-x86-64-linux-binary.tar.bz2), and running

```
sudo bash install.sh
```

However, I was curious about how I would be able to uninstall it? It has no Makefile (as it is not a source archive), so `make uninstall` or anything similar would be impossible. The same applies for the Truecrypt 7.1a binary too.

> How can I remove these kind of software?

Comment: Don't do that. Install the system binaries. If you want more recent versions, they are generally available (and easily backportable) from more recent versions of Ubuntu. In a pinch you could use the Debian version, which is the same thing. For more about backports see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671 Ping me if you want to know more.

Comment: I looked at `install.sh`. It installs in various locations under /usr/local. Even better, it **tells you the pathname after it installs each file**. Just run install.sh again, look at the output, and remove whatever it creates under /usr/local, as well as any `.old` files. It also runs `install-info`; I don't know offhand what system files that touches.

Comment: @mark-plotnic Yeah, I managed to figure that out but thanks anyway. It seems to be doing a few other things too { (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156413/how-can-i-effectively-purge-a-manually-installed-package?noredirect=1#comment256107_156414) }, I guess they might be install-info's doings.

Answer (score 1):

You can open `install.sh` and look what it did. Then you'll have to go through the tedious process of undoing it manually.

But, maybe it was installed in `/usr/local` and not `/usr/`?

Lastly, another approach would be finding the binary (e.g. `/usr/bin/truecrypt`), check its change time (`ctime`) and then using `find` to list the files which have a similar `ctime` or `mtime`.

`find` has the option `-newer` and `-newerXY`. check it out.

Comment: I've checked `install.sh`, all it did was move some fasl and other binary files around, then changed some environment variables and stuff like that. I was wondering if there was a simple way than manually purging every shred of it

Comment: I have one more idea: You could check `install.sh` for a path where the install goes (usually configurable!), change that to `/tmp/test` and run `bash install.sh`. Now you can check the `/tmp/test/` folder and files layout and run a script removing that files from `/` too.

Comment: Yeah, thanks; that's a good one! All I need to do is mention `$INSTALL_ROOT` while installing :)

Comment: Ok, I did manage to remove all the files. However, when I run `$ sbcl` now, it says `bash: /usr/local/bin/sbcl: No such file or directory`. I guess the reason it's not saying `sbcl: command not found` is that sbcl must have set some env var down the road, does that sounds correct? (I'm pretty new to bash and all this)

Comment: it seems that `sbcl` is a wrapper (maybe just a shell script, or an alias) which then calls `/usr/local/bin/sbcl`. Check: `which sbcl`, `whereis sbcl` `alias`, `grep sbcl .bashrc`. You might find something.

Comment: `$ whereis sbcl`  `sbcl: /etc/sbcl.rc` The file contains a lisp if statement that loads `/etc/lisp-config.lisp` file which refers to `/var/lib/common-lisp-controller/lisp-config.lisp` which tells me to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure common-lisp-controller` which says `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: common-lisp-controller is broken or not fully installed`. `sudo apt-get purge common-lisp-controller` removed the package's remains and now there seem to be peace. Until next time...

Comment: glad you made it. Now you know that installing a package manually can be very inconvenient -- try to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

*These are not general solutions but pertain to the two softwares I mentioned in my question- SBCL 1.2.3 and Truecrypt 7.1a*

**For SBCL**

Using the method Sebastian mentioned in the comments, I did this:

1. `# INSTALL_ROOT=/temp/asbcl sh install.sh`
2. This provided me with following files/ directories (might change in future versions/ across platforms)(Default INSTALL_ROOT is /usr/local/):

(i) INSTALL_ROOT/bin/sbcl

(ii) INSTALL_ROOT/lib/sbcl/

(iii) INSTALL_ROOT/share/doc/sbcl/

(iv) INSTALL_ROOT/share/man/man1/sbcl.1

Removing these files did the trick

3. `# apt-get purge common-lisp-controller`

**For TRUECRYPT 7.1a**

Run `/usr/bin/truecrypt-uninstall.sh`, they provide it already.