# Installing older versions of python packages with apt-get (specifically wxpython)

Tags: ubuntu, python

I've been beating my head against the wall trying to troubleshoot a graphical program with a WX backend.  We've found that wxPython `2.8.10` work fine, and seemingly any newer releases doesn't.  Despite all the help I received to building wxPython from source

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988150/how-to-get-wxpython-2-8-on-ubuntu/28031967#28031967

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457647/how-do-i-install-wxpython-in-virtualenv

The build process failed, and we tried every single approach listed.  In any case, we found that making a symbolic link to the system-python's wx worked fine, but unfortunately `apt-get install` left us with `2.8.12`.  My question is how can I `apt-get install` an older version of wxpython, or any package for that matter?

I'm on Ubuntu MATE 14.04, but have verified this problem occurs on OSX and Ubuntu 12, so it's probably not an OS-dependent issue.

Comment: You could probably rebuild older versions on your system if they don't install directly. When you say "older version of wxpython", what version do you mean, precidely? And which release of Ubuntu is it contained in? Also, I'm unclear what the word "mate" is doing there.

Comment: Sorry I mean Ubuntu MATE 14.04.  We need version 2.8.10 of wxpython.  I'll edit my question to reflect these.

Comment: Do you need 2.8.12 as well as 2.8.10 installed side by side, or would replacing 2.8.12 with 2.8.10 work for you? If the latter, you could simply build a 2.8.10 binary Debian package and stick it in the place of 2.8.12. The packaging for 2.8.12 would most likely work for 2.8.10, modulo Ubuntu-specific patches, because the versions are so similar.

Comment: Replacing is totally fine.  Would you be able to elaborate a bit about this in an answer?

Comment: Sure, but since I don't actually use your OS (Debian user), it will have to be a bit sketchy. Feel free to ask for elaboration.

Comment: That's fine.  What OS are you using?  Ubuntu MATE is basically Ubuntu and should work the same.

Comment: Debian wheezy (7.7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seem to have trouble compiling from source, why not install the package straight from the Ubuntu repositories?

If you do a search on http://packages.ubuntu.com/ for `wxPython` over all versions, you get [this result](http://packages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search_packages.pl?keywords=wxPython&searchon=all&subword=1&version=dapper&release=all) and under the **Package python-wxversion** title on that page you will find:

[lucid-updates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid-updates/python-wxversion) (python): wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (wxPython version selector) [universe] **2.8.10.1-0ubuntu1.2**: all

On that page, click the [all](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid-updates/all/python-wxversion/download) button, download the package manually and install it by `sudo dpkg --install python-wxversion_2.8.10.1-0ubuntu1.2_all.deb`

### Warning

Installing .deb files straight from the repositories, *will* have these packages updated automatically by the Ubuntu Software updater, so don't forget to `echo python-wxversion hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections` after you've painstakingly installed it to keep it at that version!

Comment: @AdamHughes Note that if it doesn't install cleanly for some reason, `apt-get -f install` is usually an effective way to remove it again. or of course you can just remove ti manually, with `apt-get purge python-wxversion`.

Comment: @AdamHughes You might want to replace `python-wxgtk2.8` too, from the same place.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do this.  Turns out that the older version of wxpython I need is not compatible with python 2.7, so this is all a moot point, but this did work at least in terms of getting the older version.  Thanks both of you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of how to replace wxPython 2.8.12 with 2.8.10. This will *probably* work, but without actually trying it out, I can't be sure.

You might find this question/answer useful as reference:
[How can I install more recent versions of software than what Debian provides?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671). What you are trying to do here isn't exactly a backport, but it is similar.

1. Check and see if Ubuntu happens to have a version of 2.8.10 floating
   around in recent releases. If so, you could try to rebuild that on
   your system. If not you'll need to do this the hard way.
2. Download the source of wxPython 2.8.12.

   ```
   apt-get source python-wxgtk2.8
   ```

   This would download the source for `wxwidgets2.8` for you. This assumes
   the presence of the appropriate `deb-src` lines in `/etc/apt.sources.list`.
3. Get an upstream version of wxPython `2.8.10`, unpack it, and copy
   the Debian directory from the `wxwidgets2.8` Debian/Ubuntu source.
   You'll need to rename the tarball to conform to the Debian naming
   scheme, and also update the Debian changelog. If you can get that to
   build, you're good. The  build command I normally use is

   ```
   debuild -uc -us
   ```

   using `debuild` from the `devscripts` package. You'll probably need
   to install some build dependencies. You could first run
   `dpkg-checkbuilddeps` to check the build dependencies situation.
4. An alternative method is to use the sources from
   http://snapshot.debian.org/package/wxwidgets2.8/. These are for
   Debian, but will probably work on an Ubuntu system. These are Debian
   sources, you you can just rebuild them directly.

NOTE: If you do a successful install of `2.8.10`, you will probably need to do something to stop apt and friends upgrading wxPython back to `2.8.12`. There ar different ways to do this, but a simple and effective way is to use epochs. But this is a detail that can be addressed if a rebuilding effort is successful.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob.  Can you elaborate on step 1: Check and see if Ubuntu happens to have a version of 2.8.10 floating around in recent releases. If so, you could try to rebuild that on your system. If not you'll need to do this the hard way.  How would I check this, and if I do find it, what does it mean to rebuild?

Comment: @AdamHughes since I'm not a Ubuntu user, I'm not sure, but does Ubuntu archive earier releases of packages in any central place, like snapshot.debian.org? If not, check the version of wxPython 2.8 for the preceding version of Ubuntu. This isn't very likely to work, hence the rest of the answer, but if it did, it would be the most painless way. Rebuild just means build the sources in a binary Debian package. See the reference I added to the beginning of the question.

Comment: Ok, well thanks for the info.  I'll see if I can makesense of it and get it to work.

Comment: @AdamHughes If you are not familiar with Debian packaging, it is a useful thing to know about if you use Debian or its derivatives. There is some overhead, but it is not excessive.

Comment: I thought Ubuntu was a Debian OS by default?  But I only know this superficially

Comment: @AdamHughes Ubuntu is a Debian derivative. Meaning that it is derived from Debian, but is not itself Debian. There are other Debian derivatives, but Ubuntu is the best known.

Comment: For the old Ubuntu archives: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/