# Snapshotting a Linux container in Debian

Tags: debian, command, lxc

I know that the command `$ lxc-snapshot` [exists somewhere](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lxc-snapshot.1.html), but it seems that it's [not available on Debian](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=lxc-snapshot&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en)? Forgive my Linux ignorance - but how do I get a hold of this capability? Is there an alternative for Debian?

Also, if you need this info, the result of `$ uname -a`:

`Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Have you tried `apt-file search "lxc-snapshot"`?

Comment: It looks like is available in a more recent version of lxc than the one you have, since `apt-file` lists it as being in lxc, but my version (wheezy) does not have it. Backporting lxc is probably an option, though you might have to also upgrade the kernel. I'm guessing you are running wheezy. For future reference, note that `lsb_release -a` is the information to post.

Comment: deb7 is wheezy. So yes @Jaska is running wheezy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lxc-snapshot` is listed in the version of lxc in testing/unstable, which at this time of writing are both the same, namely `1:1.0.6-6`.

You can see the list of packages at
[File list of package lxc/jessie/amd64](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/lxc/filelist).

Backporting lxc should not be a problem. It does not have much by way of dependencies. Comment if you need more details about this. Generic instructions are at
[How can I install more recent versions of software than what Debian provides?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671)

I haven't checked to see if you need to upgrade your kernel, but I think 3.2 probably offers sufficiently recent support for the `1.0.6` version of the LXC userspace tools.