# How to install `roundcube` without adding back-ports in `Debian`?

Tags: linux, debian, backports, webmail

Trying to install `roundcube` by issuing following command

```
apt-get -y install roundcube roundcube-pgsql roundcube-plugins roundcube-plugins-extra php-net-ldap2
```

getting following error.

```
E: Unable to locate package roundcube
E: Unable to locate package roundcube-pgsql
E: Unable to locate package roundcube-plugins
E: Unable to locate package roundcube-plugins-extra
```

**Problem**
Not allowed to use back-port

```
echo "deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
```

How shall I go about this?

```
OS: Debian latest
```

Comment: The packages are available now except for roundcube-plugins-extra, I couldn't find that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found, there is no roundcube package for Debian 8.x (jessie), which is currently the latest release.

As I see it, your options are:

1. Install a backport of roundcube. There isn't an official one yet, so you can do the backport yourself. It's fairly straightforward - just take the source package for stretch and rebuilt it on a jessie system, following [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation) and the [backport guidelines](http://backports.debian.org/Contribute/). **I would strongly recommend this.**
2. Install the stretch package. It should still install on a jessie system as the two releases have not yet diverged a great deal. Not really recommended, but it "should" work.
3. Install roundcube from source. Not recommended. Debian is a binary package based distribution, so install as much as you can from binary packages.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671. Linked in the backports tag wiki.