# Debian libtiff4

Tags: libraries, backports

I am trying to install a printer driver package (Canon Pixma MX437 cnijfilter-mx430series-3.70-1-deb) on my system running Debian 8.1 3.16.0-4-amd64 Jessie xfce.

I get a dependency error that package libtiff4 is not installed:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cnijfilter-mx430series:
 cnijfilter-mx430series depends on libtiff4; however:
  Package libtiff4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package cnijfilter-mx430series (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cnijfilter-mx430series
```

Where I can find this package?

Comment: Re backports, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671. Where did you obtain cnijfilter-mx430series-3.70-1-deb from? Details/link, please.

Comment: http://search-my.canon-asia.com/canon__my_en__my_p_en/search.x?q=&ie=utf8&cat=0&ct=Support&pagemax=10&imgsize=1&pdf=ok&zoom=1&hf=category%09zubaken&cf=model_sm%3APIXMA+MX437&modelName=PIXMA+MX437&ref=support-my.canon-asia.com&pid=zw8J-w9S14cluORnbfpcPw..&qid=S7MTrgZv76VYqrwwu0xoG0Xm9Eg3J02D&d=DOWNLOADS%09Linux and http://support-my.canon-asia.com/contents/MY/EN/0100412601.html

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `libtiff4` [isn't available](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=libtiff4) for Debian 8.x (jessie).

As I see it, there are two options to install it:

1. Install the binary [package for wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libtiff4). There's no guarantee that this would work as the package has other dependencies that may not be met.
2. Download the source for the most recent package for wheezy and create a forward-port of it for jessie (basically, the same process as a backport, but from an older to newer release). This is probably the better option (as the dependencies will be correctly met), but would require more skills than **1**. There is a [guide](https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation) that is a good starting point.

As an outside option, you *may* also be able to get your printer working with [CUPS](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemPrinting#Canon). Certainly, there is a [Mac OS X](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100569401.html) CUPS driver for the 430 series but you may need to get someone to install the driver on a Mac to be able to access the required files (they're packaged in a `DMG` file, unfortunately).

**Update** Corrected reference to backport

Comment: @user125092 This would really be a forward-port, rather than a backport... Installing the binary package for wheezy is probably not the way to go; I'd try rebuilding `libtiff4` on jessie. I imagine there are utilities on Linux to unpack a DMG archive. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/38112/how-can-i-open-a-dmg-file for suggestions.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thanks for the correction - I've updated my answer re: backport terminology.