# Installing libusb 1.0.9 on Debian 8 Jessie

Tags: debian, software-installation, source

I am new to Linux so I don't really know how to install from source.

I went to libusb.org and downloaded the latest version of libusb.

- Where do I put it?
- When I follow the install instructions, where does it end up?
- How can I make sure that it has installed correctly?

The reason I need to install it (and many other things) is because I need to use this project: http://www.libimobiledevice.org/ and there are many things to install, but I will start with libusb 1.0.9 first, and then I install USBMUXD.

Answer (score 1):

As with most software for Linux, both `libusb` and `libimobiledevice` are [packaged](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libusb) for [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libimobiledevice). There is no need to download and compile it yourself! Just install it:

```
sudo apt install libimobiledevice-utils libimobiledevice-doc
```

will get you the command-line tools shipped with `libimobiledevice`, as well as the documentation. You probably don't want to use those tools, however, since they're fairly low-level. Instead, try using `gtkpod` (`sudo apt install gtkpod`), a graphical application which uses `libimobiledevice`. There are a few other things which may do what you want; if you run

```
apt-cache rdepends libimobiledevice4
```

you will get a list of packages that use libimobiledevice for some things; you can look at their description with `apt-cache show` and install them with `sudo apt install`

Comment: thanks. I won't need the graphicals of that library, I really only need USBMUXD, iFuse and LibUSB, as I am developing my own software,.

Comment: I tried `apt-cache rdepends libimobiledevice4 ` and and then `sudo apt install usbmuxd`, and then I write  `usbmuxd -V` to check the version and it is 1.0.9 while the latest version of `usbmuxd` seems to be 1.1.0. Why didn't the latest version get installed?

Comment: @vaid "Why didn't the latest version get installed?" Because that is the version in jessie. In general, if it is a leaf package, you can often backport it. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671