# How to build & install Debian package and it's dependencies from source on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: debian, ubuntu, package-management

What is the most convenient way to build and install packages that are found from [Debian Tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/?) on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver?

For example I am interested in this unstable version of [gdal](https://packages.debian.org/source/unstable/gdal) which cannot be found from Ubuntu bionic repository.

So I would need to build the package from source and install it's dependencies.

```
apt update
apt install -y build-essential devscripts equivs
dget https://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gdal/gdal_3.2.2+dfsg-1.dsc
dpkg-source -x gdal_3.2.2+dfsg-1.dsc
cd gdal-3.2.2+dfsg/
mk-build-deps -i
```

Problem at the moment is that some of the dependencies are not found from Ubuntu repositories. Is it somehow possible to have them automatically installed from the debian source also?

```
Broken gdal-build-deps:amd64 Depends on libdeflate-dev:amd64 < none @un H >
  Removing gdal-build-deps:amd64 because I can't find libdeflate-dev:amd64
```

Comment: **beep** installing Debian packages on Ubuntu? Stop right there: https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian . What you can do instead is to build packages from sources, doing a sort of backport.

Comment: I understand. What about the dependencies? Is it possible to build and install them from source also? I edited the original post.

Comment: Not really - some of those dependencies have dependencies! Either use Ubuntu or use Debian. Unfortunately, Ubuntu choose to use a .deb package naming scheme - but Ubuntu debs are mostly incompatible with Debian debs (and vice versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you’re using Ubuntu, you should use [the Ubuntu package source code](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdal) rather than Debian’s. The overall strategy is similar; you’d only need to change the `dget` line to

```
dget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/gdal/3.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu1/gdal_3.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu1.dsc
```

As you suspect, you’ll have to do this for any missing build-dependency, again using Ubuntu packages; so for [libdeflate](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdeflate) you’d use

```
dget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/libdeflate/1.7-1ubuntu1/libdeflate_1.7-1ubuntu1.dsc
```

See also [How can I install more recent versions of software than what Debian provides?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/86440)