# How to get the build procedure for a Debian package?

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg, configure, pkg-config

I want to build a version of some software that is more recent than the one that is currently available as a stable release Debian package.

To do this, however, other than using a more recent version of the source code, I would like to follow, as closely as possible, the build procedure that was used to build the Debian package for this software in the stable release.

At the very least, I would like to specify the same configuration flags and the same values for relevant environment variables during the build as was done for the stable release Debian package for this software.

**Q:** How can I find the build procedure for a specific (stable release) Debian package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The build procedure for a Debian package is described by its source package. If you have a Debian system, you can download that using

```
apt source ${package}
```

if your `sources.list` contains the appropriate `deb-src` entries. If you have multiple releases referenced in your repositories, you can specify that you’re after the `stable` release:

```
apt source ${package}/stable
```

(assuming you have `stable` in your repositories). You might find the newer release you’re interested in already packaged in `testing` or `unstable`, in which case using that instead will save you some time — see [How can I install more recent versions of software than what Debian provides?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/86440) for instructions in this situation.

In the source package, the main files to look at are `debian/control` and `debian/rules`. For example, the `hello` package‘s [`control` file](https://sources.debian.org/src/hello/2.10-2/debian/control/) specifies that it builds with `debhelper` in compatibility level 9 (see `man debhelper` for details) and its [`rules` file](https://sources.debian.org/src/hello/2.10-2/debian/control/) specifies that it uses the default `dh` settings to build (including the default `dpkg` build flags, see `dpkg-buildflags`).

If your source package specifies how to update it, you might only need to run

```
uscan
```

to update the source package, change to the corresponding directory, add a changelog entry for the new version with

```
dch -v 1.2.3-0.1 "New upstream release."
```

(replacing `1.2.3` as appropriate), then

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

to build the package.

The main gotcha when updating a package in this way is that any patches may need to be updated. If `debian/patches/series` exists and isn’t empty, you’ll need to check each patch in turn, by running `quilt push`; see `man quilt` for details.

Comment: A note if you're new to building Debian packages: Install the `build-essential` package to get all the tools you'll need, and run `apt build-dep ${package}` as root to install the build dependencies of the particular package you're building.

Comment: Also a good idea to keep the [Debian Packaging Tutorial](https://www.debian.org/doc/devel-manuals#packaging-tutorial) handy.